# URL rewrite using PCRE expression - append prefix to all incoming URIs except one pattern

Tags: regex, pcre, regex-greedy, urlrewriter

i am using match expression as `https://([^/]*)/(.*)` and replace expression as **constantprefix/$2** and trying to rewrite incoming URL by adding '/constantprefix' to all URLs

for Below URLs it is working as expected:

1. https://hostname/incomingURI is converting to
   /constantprefix/incomingURI
2. https://hostname/ is converting to /constantprefix/
3. https://hostname/login/index.aspx is converting to
   /constantprefix/login/index.aspx

i am having problem for the URLs which already starting with /constantprefix, i am seeing two /constantprefix/constantprefix in the output URL which I am not looking for, is there any way we can avoid that ?

if incoming URL is https://hostname/constantprefix/login/index.aspx then output URL is becoming https://hostname/constantprefix/constantprefix/login/index.aspx 
may i know how i can avoid /constantprefix/constantprefix from match expression ?

Comment: Perhaps just add a test, like `unless $url =~ |https://([^/]*)/$prefix|` (untested). Then it works with the string twice but it's a straight-up scan, shouldn't be too bad efficiency wise

Comment: thanks for your quick response, are you suggesting the match expression as https://([^/]*)/(.*)|https://([^/]*)/$constantprefix ?

Comment: oh sorry -- I meant that you do your substitution _unless_ it already matches `$prefix` at that position.  So to check whether it's there and if not run the substitution.  It is much simpler than messing with the working regex, and it is clear what it does.  It does look at the string twice, but the check should be quite quick.

Comment: i am using IBM DataPower URL-write feature, which doesn't have option to give any condition... i can pass match expression and replace expression only.. i am trying to see if there is anyway we can skip a particular URL pattern like /constantprefix/*

Comment: Try `https://[^/]*/(?!constantprefix(?:/|$))(.*)` with `constantprefix/$1`

Comment: https://([^/]*)/(?!constantprefix(?:/|$))(.*) is working perfectly. Thanks alot Casimir, really appreciate your help!!                                                          can we make constantprefix case sensitive in the above expression ?

Comment: @sarma  Oh, sorry. You nicely specify PCRE and never mention Perl. I am used to Perl-related regex posts, my mistake. (You did get a good answer so all is well :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with:

```
https://[^/]*/(?!constantprefix(?:/|$))(.*)
```

using the replacement string:

```
constantprefix/$1
```

`(?!...)` is a negative lookahead and means *not followed by*. It's only a test and doesn't consume characters (this kind of elements in a pattern are also called *"zero-width assertions"* as a lookbehind or anchors `^` and `$`).

The first capture group in your pattern was useless, I removed it.